# How to select Birthday(Month) from drop down in the google Sign up page by using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate google signup page. But when i am trying to select Birthday I am getting an error in eclipse.

Error( Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (724, 543)

When i wrote the code first time it worked and when i run again its giving me this error.

```
package signup.page;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SignUpPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "C:\\Drive E\\MISM\\Online Certification\\java2\\library\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println("Application title is =============" + driver.getTitle());

        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]"));
        searchBox.sendKeys(("Google Account Sign Up"));
        searchBox.submit();

        WebElement createAccount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"rso\"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h3/a"));
        createAccount.click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("Mehadi");

        driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("Hasan");

        driver.findElement(By.id("GmailAddress")).sendKeys("MehadiHasan0505050505");

        driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("Mehadi-00599$$");

        driver.findElement(By.id("PasswdAgain")).sendKeys("Mehadi-00599$$");

        // ******
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-menuitem-content' and text()='April']")).click();
        // ******

    }

}
```

Console log

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 41414
Only local connections are allowed.

Application title is =============Google

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (724, 543)

  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 43 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8), userDataDir=C:\Users\saimu\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir16684_25921}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=63.0.3239.132, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: fde8c1cdeb468c439b01363d15398049
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
    at signup.page.SignUpPage.main(SignUpPage.java:42)
```

Comment: I executed from my end and its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an know issue in chromeDriver 2.31 fail to click element which not in current view port.

Upgrade chromedriver to 2.33 or 2.34 should fix your problem.

[image]

[More detail](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1852)